# How to stop gcp's Static Ip Charge in deleted project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I removed my project in 2020 but google still make $7 cost (**Static Ip Charge**) every month , how to stop it?
[image: cost]

And it's my current vpc network , there is no project in it.

[image: vpx]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes a few days to completely delete all resources in your GCP project.

So some resources are being charged even after project deletion.

First, Restore deleted project.

You can restore deleted project via `RESOURCES PENDING DELETION` in manage resource page

[image]

Second, Delete your static ip address.

And then delete restored project again.

If you don't want to be charged for resources in deleted project like this case, Make sure to delete resources before project deletion.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted this project in May 2020 , and it should deleted in June(I remember browser alerted that).But **gcp's program keep this project to 2021 just because static ip is not deleted**. Awsome engineers

Comment: @ToknsitToknsit - Raise a support ticket (free) with Google Cloud Billing support. They will help you.

Comment: I like how you can't just hard delete a project without painstaking going through every resource, shutting it down, and then deleting it hoping that it won't accidentally incur a bunch of money.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same, Google take 7$ a month,
please go to Billing Report if you see "Static Ip Charge" take money,
[image]
you can do as my way
Go to the left panel
VPC network -
External IP addresses
and delete it.
Recove project if you delete it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30710009)